# Classes & Activities in Android

Tags: android, class, android-activity

Another Java/Android newbie...

My Activity contains a delcaration for a variable of a class that I've defined...
    public Teams theTeams = null;
Within the onCreate method of this Activity, I create an object of that class...
    Teams theTeams = new Teams();
I've been able to make some changes to this object...
    theTeams.setName("A", "Jets");
... which assigns "Jets" to a string in the class.
However, from within a private method of the Activity, attempts to refer to "theTeams" give me a null pointer error.  I guess there's something about object visibility that I'm not understanding.  Can someone clarify?

Comment: would be nice to see some code here. you can post it by selecting the code sample button in the question edit dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared first `public Teams theTeams = null;`
Then in the `onCreate` method, you have this

```
Teams theTeams = new Teams();
```

So you are initializing a new  `theTeams` object of type `Team` inside the `onCreate`, which you can see only in the scope of `onCreate`.

So when you call a method on `theTeams` in your private method, the method is called in the object you have declared first outside the `onCreate` (which is still null)

So inside, your `onCreate`, you have to use:

```
theTeams = new Teams();
```

Something like the following should work (untested):

```
private Teams theTeams = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    theTeams = new Teams();
}

private void myMethod() {
    theTeams.getName();
}
```